# Receiving duplicated results from UNION in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use SQL Server I use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE table1
(
     ID    VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Name  VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
     Price INTEGER  NOT NULL,
     Date  DATE 
);

INSERT INTO table1 (ID, Name, Price, Date) 
VALUES ('000212', 'Rod', 200, NULL);

CREATE TABLE table2
(
     Descr    VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Identity VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
     amount   INTEGER NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table2 (Descr, Identity, amount) 
VALUES ('Silver rod', '000212', 3);

CREATE TABLE table3
(
     Type       VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     Price      INTEGER,
     Condition  INTEGER  NOT NULL,
     CatalogNum VARCHAR(10)  NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO table3 (Type, Price, Condition, CatalogNum) 
VALUES ('Metal', NULL, 8, '000212');

INSERT INTO table3 (Type, Price, Condition, CatalogNum) 
VALUES ('Wood', 300, 1, '000313');

WITH IdList AS 
(
    SELECT ID AS MasterId
    FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT Identity
    FROM table2
    UNION
    SELECT CatalogNum
    FROM table3
)
SELECT
    i.MasterID,
    t1.*,
    t2.*,
    t3.*
FROM 
    IdList as i
LEFT JOIN 
    table1 as t1 ON t1.ID = i.MasterID
LEFT JOIN 
    table2 as t2 ON t2.Identity = i.MasterID
LEFT JOIN 
    table3 as t3 ON t3.CatalogNum = i.MasterID;
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/541d6/2)

In order to combine several tables with the same product ID.

However for some reason I get multiple duplicated results. I.E. instead of getting one row with unique ID, I get 7 (I currently have 7 tables unlike the code above, but not necessarily - I also get 2, and 3 duplicated rows) with the same result.

Just to mention, this is a code which I found here and just edited and added 7 tables instead of only three that in the example above.

Comment: You sample data only produces 2 rows, and they are both different. I don't see the problem.

Comment: The duplications are caused by the JOIN operations

Comment: What's the alternative?

Comment: To ask the real question you are interested at. For some reason it seems like the hardest thing to do in SO. Supply a data sample that demonstrate the issue and the desired results, both in tabular format (you can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)

Comment: Hi @David. It's not really clear from the code what you're trying to achieve. If you could elaborate on what you're trying to do (rather than how you're trying to do it) and then also provide the output you're getting and the output you're expecting that will really help us to figure out what's wrong and suggest solutions.